# How to loop throgh a set of rows, count.if by each row, then sum the total result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

As an equivalent simplified example of what i intend, there is this worksheet with any sequence of 5 numbers beetween 1-9 each from columns A to E and for many rows:

```
  | A| B| C| D| E|
1 | 1| 5| 6| 8| 9|
2 | 2| 5| 7| 8| 9|
...
50| 1| 3| 4| 6| 7|
```

Then I want to check for how many combinations of any two numbers occur by each row along all the rows and filling a combination array with the result:

```
  | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|
 1|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 2|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 3|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 4|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 5|  |  |  | x|  |  |  |  |  |
 6|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 7|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 8|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 9|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
```

Above, "x" would represent the value of in how many rows there is any occurance of the combination of the numbers 4 and 5.

I achieved my goal easily by VBA code, but wanted to know how to do this by excel-formula, since it generally will be faster.

Just in case anyone one want to check the VBA code that already works for this task:

```
Sub NPairs()
Dim Rn As Long
Dim Cn As Long

For Nrow = 2 To 10
    For Ncol = 2 To 10
        If NCol = NRow Then GoTo NextN 'Skip, cause would search the combination of the same numbers.

        Rn = Plan2.Cells(NRow, 1).Value2
        Cn = Plan2.Cells(1, NCol).Value2

        Plan2.Cells(Nrow, Ncol) = NMatch(Rn, Cn)
NextN:
    Next
Next

End Sub

Private Function Nmatch(Rnumber As Long, Cnumber As Long) As Long
Lastrow = Plan1.Cells(Plan1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
M = 0
For R = 2 To Lastrow
    For C = 1 To 5

        If Plan1.Cells(R, C).Value2 = Rnumber Then
            For Cl = 1 To 5
                If Plan1.Cells(R, Cl).Value2 = Cnumber Then M = M + 1
            Next
        End If

    Next
Next

Nmatch = M
End Function
```

This could be fastened by using array or dictionary, I know. What I want to know is if that is possible to do the same, in a more simple way, by excel-formula.

Comment: In the function Nmatch, the variable Lnumber is not defined. Should that be Rnumber?

Comment: @JohnRC Yes. You're right. Editing It.

Answer (score 3):

If your concern is speed, then VBA will probably be faster in this case. But here is an idea to do it with formulas only:

1. Create an intermediate matrix with as many rows as in the source matrix and a column for each number (1 .. 9). Use a formula to indicate whether the corresponding row contains the number identified by the column.
2. Based on this intermediate matrix, look for the rows which have TRUE for the two numbers of interest.
3. You can then hide the intermediate matrix if so desired.

Here is how it would look:

[image]

The middle matrix is the intermediate one. The formula in G2 is:

```
=COUNTIF($A2:$E2, G$1)
```

You can copy it to the other cells of that matrix

The rightmost matrix is the final result. The formula in R2 is:

```
=IF(R$1=$Q2, COUNTIFS(INDEX($G$2:$O$9, 0, R$1),">1"), 
             COUNTIFS(INDEX($G$2:$O$9, 0, R$1),">0", INDEX($G$2:$O$9, 0, $Q2), ">0"))
```

The `INDEX` function is used to retrieve the appropriate column in the intermediate matrix. The one column in the intermediate matrix is chosen based on the current row (in the final matrix) and the other one is based on the current column. Both must have the value TRUE (in the same row) to be counted.

After your comment, I wrapped the formula in an `IF` to deal with the case of the main diagonal: in that case the single number must occur more than once in a row for the latter to be counted.

You can download the above sheet from [Google docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSTwt435ZVL6sKwZgiiv4Lv-t6rUSjybl2g-b07eLP4t45geRQcA2sf4rP9b3kmQZg2lUzPl7e1DikY/pub?output=xlsx)

Comment: Thanks, although it reaches the goal, there are two problems: In a scenario where i have lot of numbers, using an "intermediate" matrix/table, may be an issue, since it can change the structure of the file.
And your formula returns an undesired result when comparing a number with itself, since both index conditions will point to the same column and return the sum within it not the row. But easily corrigible.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "it can change the structure of the file". Would putting it in another sheet (maybe even a hidden one) solve your concern? About the comparison of a number with itself: I assume you refer to the main diagonal in the final table. Your VBA code omitted that case, so I assumed it was not important to you. Would you want to count the rows where that (single) number occurs twice instead?

Comment: Imagine a sheet with 60000 numbers and combinations as explained, by your valid solution, i would have to build an entire new big sheet just for the true/false verification. It is still a valid solution.
About the main diagonal, of course i did avoid its calculation in the VBA code, it is clearly commented in the line:
"If NCol = NRow Then GoTo NextN 'Skip, cause would search the combination of the same numbers."

Comment: Yes, but you would also have to build the structure of the final matrix, with 60000 rows and 60000 columns, right? And concerning the VBA code: that is indeed what I noticed. So are you saying your VBA code was incomplete and you still wanted the result for the main diagonal?

Comment: Yes, I'd have to build two big tables. Your solution is quite good, but in that scenario I would stick with VBA code instead. And concerning to the VBA code in the sub "Npairs", The if condition inside the for loop is for checking same number at row and column and skiping it, thus avoiding unnecessary calculation in the main diagonal. The code is complete and run as is.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&J$1&"*"&$I2&"*",$A$1:$A$50&$B$1:$B$50&$C$1:$C$50&$D$1:$D$50&$E$1:$E$50)),1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$I2&"*"&J$1&"*",$A$1:$A$50&$B$1:$B$50&$C$1:$C$50&$D$1:$D$50&$E$1:$E$50)),1,0)))`

This is an array formula, while still in the formula bar hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Using wildcards with `SEARCH()` we can look for the numbers within built strings, then reverse the serach order to catch both instances. I build a binary array based of the results and `SUM()` them.

`*` equates to any number of any character (can also be 0 characters). Using this we can establish whether the 2 numbers appear anywhere in the 5 positions, this is then flipped to catch if they are in the other order.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this return the sum of the relative position of the numbers inside the strings?
And since the sheet has no string at all, just numbers isolated by its own cells, sorry but i did not get the point of using the search function.

Comment: @Musicodelic The point of using search is to allow the use of wildcards... The search returns a number based on the position within the string I have built for the row of 5 values. The `ISNUMBER()` equates this to a Boolean result that is used to provide either 1 or 0 to be summed.  You could remove the second IF statement to make the order relative to y,x (or the first for x,y) so the table wouldn't express symmetry. Esentially as I am looking to sum an array I cannot use Match as that will only provide a single result and `IF()` alone wont accept wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar approach to @trincot, with an intermediate table, but this table would be ten columns with the set of ten pairs of digits from the source table:

[image]

Then use `Countif()` to count the occurrences of the pairs in a separate table:

[image]

Using named ranges would make the formulas even simpler.